# Can new users with 55 reps points offer a bounty?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, reputation, bounties, new-users

I'm a new user on [superuser.com](http://superuser.com). I asked a question which is very important to me. I did not manage to get a proper answer.

After some work on the site, I managed to get 55 reputation points. The question is 3 days old now, but I can't find the "start a bounty" option at the end of my question.

The question was asked when I had 1 reputation point, and no badges.

Comment: It was on Super User

Comment: Please also see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7046/how-to-get-attention-for-your-old-unanswered-questions

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> You must have at least 100 reputation to offer a bounty.

From [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work/16067#16067).

(as of October 2010, you only need 75)

Comment: Why does it say 75 [here](http://askubuntu.com/privileges/set-bounties) then?

Comment: @Seth Because that's correct. This answer is 3 years old; the value has been lowered since.

Comment: Ah, my bad.  I didn't notice that.

Answer (score 3):

On the other hand, you can try to go the the site's chat and ask people to put a bounty on your question. If some "high-rep" user considers it reasonable, they can help you. I know this has happened before.

You need only 20 rep to enter the chat.